# Implement IIS Load Balancing across Sites or Applications -- not Servers

Tags: iis, arr

I have an IIS Application that returns data via a SOAP interface. All calls are atomic. Due to issues communicating with the back-end , this IIS app is not thread safe. Issuing more than one call at a time leads instability. The IIS app IS STABLE running multiple instances ( I have tested 100 apps) **in separate Application Pools.** I have configured multiple instances of this IIS app and then used a load balancing strategy (within the client) to invoke the service. Only one call goes through each service at a time. I have urls like:

- http://server/app1
- http://server/app2
- http://server/app3
- http://server/app4
- ...
- http://server/app100

app1-100 are identical copies running under separate pools.

I would like to configure a main url to be:

- http://server/app

How would I go about configuring this ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting up a [Web Garden](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720391(v=vs.71).aspx) in IIS which will create multiple worker processes for the same site. The issue to keep in mind is that if your app keeps session state it will not persist across processes without storing it in a shared persistence store (e.g. Redis).

To setup a web garden edit the properties of the web site app pool and set the Maximum Worker Processes to a number greater than 1.

IIS will round robin requests between worker processes.

**Update**

The above does not actually enforce a single request at a time. To enforce a concurrent request limit you need to adjust advanced settings of the web site. 
* Right click the web site node
* Manage Web Site
* Advanced Settings
* Change the Maximum Concurrent Connections

If you set this to 1 then regardless how many app pools you have running it will only process one at a time. You can try set this to 2 and have 2 worker processes, as IIS should send the second one to the second process, but it's not guaranteed to serialize per app pool. To only have one at a time set Max Worker Processes to 1 and Max Concurrent Connections to 1

[image]

[image: web garden setting]

Comment: the issue I have, is I can only get this stable running under separate pools. How do I set up a web garden with separate pools ?

Comment: Exactly how I described. A web garden by definition is separate pools. Setting to 2 will cause 2 w3wp.exe processes to serve requests for your site.

Comment: I did try your suggestion, and multiple w3wp.exe were created, but I ended up with the same issue I started with. I noticed the number of w3wp instances were small, less than the number of calls going through the server. I seems I am limited to one call/app/pool at a time.

Comment: OK so this definitely will only process 1 at a time, are you seeing concurrent processing?

Comment: No I got an error indicating is could not process additional requests.

Comment: If your system has to process 1 request at a time then this is a consequence. Are able to alter the URL? E.g use a different port or query string or host? If so then you have more options. E.g HTTP:/server/app?1 directs to server/app1

Comment: I have had success in this direction--from the client.  I have a configure utility that creates n services all with the same virtual directory and unique app pools. I am considering creating a proxy service to direct calls to urls not in use. With this strategy I can hit ~100 concurrent calls.

Comment: Oh and look at URL rewrite module it might help for redirecting based on rules